# Pointers c++. Difference between p and p*

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't understand what it is supposed to print when it says `cout << x`.
and also when it says `if ( *x==*y)` that means that the letters should be equal or the positions( well of the position is equal than the letter is too).

[image]

Comment: Output of a pointer to `char` is special. The pointer is then treated as a pointer to the first `char` in a C style zero-terminated string. But these are not good example to learn C++ from.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Of course, apart from I/O, this code is as much C as it is C++. I think the teacher is trying to teach them recursion. As far as teaching recursion goes, this isn't bad at all: at least it does not spoil the technique for the students the way the factorial does :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand what it is supposed to print when it says `cout << x`.

Since `x` is of type `char*`, it is treated like a null-terminated C string on printing. If you print a pointer into the middle of a string, the suffix of the string is printed:

```
const char *str = "ABCDEFG";
const char *ptr = str + 3;
cout << ptr; // prints DEFG
```

> when it says `if ( *x==*y)` that means that the letters should be equal or the positions

`*` in this context means "the value pointed to by ...", i.e. the letters should be equal, not the positions.

Comment: The declaration `char *str = "ABCDEFG";` is invalid.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ah, of course, this C code pretends it's C++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `cout << x` it's supposed to print out the whole char array. Let's say that `char *x = "Something"` . If you enter `cout << x` , the output will be: Something . The * sign is the dereference operator and it's used to dereference a pointer(in other words to get the value of the pointer). So if you have `char *x = "Something"` and `char *y = "Some other thing"` and if you want to compare the first characters of those char arrays,you would use `if(*x == *y)` . So dereferencing a char array gets the first char. `cout << *x` the output will be: S.

Comment: Thank you! I understood how it works!